# $goQuery is only returning a single value

Tags: goinstant, goangular

I have a scope model called person that has a firstname, lastname and fullname.  My goQuery works with this:

```
$scope.person = $goQuery('person', { userName: $scope.person.findme }, { sort: { 'userName': 'asc' }, limit: 1 }).$sync();
```

The only problem I'm having is that it only populates the value for the field I'm searching and not the whole model.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

$scope.person.findme throws an error because $scope.person is not yet defined. I'm not sure how this is working at all.

Here's a working example:

```
$scope.person = $goQuery('person', 'person', { userName: 'user1' }, { sort: { 'userName': 'asc' }, limit: 1 }).$sync();

$scope.person.$add({ userName: 'user1', fname: 'a', lname: 'b'});
$scope.person.$add({ userName: 'user2', fname: 'c', lname: 'd'});
$scope.person.$add({ userName: 'user3', fname: 'e', lname: 'f'});
window.person = $scope.person;
```

If you look at the model on window.person you should see user1's ID and their data under it.

Comment: the model is already defined at the init of the controller, which is not displayed.  $goQuery is supposed to return the full model back to $scope.person, but instead, I'm only getting the userName field returned.

Comment: $scope.person = $goQuery(...) will overwrite the model you have defined in init, so I would recommend not doing it that way. Either have a separate model to handle the findme input or extend the model after $scope.person = $goQuery(...).

Comment: I was under the impression that is the desired effect. I followed the demo video instructions from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTuovru9miU

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Thank you Colin MacDonald. This is how you return results into your scope:
HTML CODE:

```
 <label>Find User:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="person.findme" placeholder="Enter Full Name to Search..." />
    <input type="button" id="Find" value="Search" ng-click="Find()" />
```

JAVA SCRIPT:

```
 $scope.Find = function () {
  console.log('entering find method...')
  $scope.person = $goQuery('person', { userName: $scope.person.findme }, { limit: 1 }).$sync();
       $scope.person.$on('ready', function () {
            var id = $scope.person.$$index[0];
                if (!id) {
                   // no results found
                   return;
                }
       $scope.person = $scope.person[id];
                       $scope.person.id = id;
       });
       };
```